# Distinct not working with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I want to remove repeated rows from a LIST using distinct.

This is the **resultset** (As you can see, index 12 and 14 are repeated)

```
id  idIndice    idName         idTipo   tamanho     caminho
12  11          Processo       3        10          C:\Program Files\Empenho\Senha.txt
13  13          Endereço       1        250         C:\Program Files\Empenho\Senha.txt
14  12          Número         2        5           C:\Program Files\Empenho\Senha.txt
15  9           Cep            5        8           C:\Program Files\Empenho\Senha.txt 
16  10          Dt. de Nasc.   4        0           C:\Program Files\Empenho\Senha.txt
12  11          Processo       3        10          C:\Program Files\Empenho\Senha.txt
14  12          Número         2        5           C:\Program Files\Empenho\Senha.txt
```

This is the **sql** I want to archieve (this does the job)

```
select DISTINCT u.id, u.idIndice, t.idName, t.idTipo, t.tamanho, l.caminho
from  tgpwebged.dbo.sistema_Indexacao as u
join  tgpwebged.dbo.sistema_Indexes as t on u.idIndice = t.id
join  tgpwebged.dbo.sistema_Documentos as l on u.idDocumento = l.id
join  tgpwebged.dbo.sistema_DocType_Index as v on t.id = v.indexId
where u.idDocumento = 10
```

This is the **LINQ** I am trying to adapt

```
var docObj = from u in context.sistema_Indexacao
join t in context.sistema_Indexes on u.idIndice equals t.id
join l in context.sistema_Documentos on u.idDocumento equals l.id
join v in context.sistema_DocType_Index on t.id equals v.indexId
join m in context.sistema_DocType on v.docTypeId equals m.id
where u.idDocumento == id
select new Gedi.Models.OperacoesModel.getDocIndex
{ ...  };
```

This is what I am trying:

```
List<Gedi.Models.OperacoesModel.getDocIndex> docIndexModelDup = docObj.ToList();
List<Gedi.Models.OperacoesModel.getDocIndex> docIndexModel =
docIndexModelDup.Distinct().ToList();
```

But I still get the same 7 rows as if there is no DISTINCT at all.

Why?

Comment: Does `getDocIndex` implement `IEquatable<getDocIndex>`?

Comment: http://blog.jordanterrell.com/post/LINQ-Distinct%28%29-does-not-work-as-expected.aspx

Comment: @Massimiliano Peluso Worked perfectly. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

If you want the Distinct performed in sql, call Distinct() before ToList().

```
var docObj = (from u in context.sistema_Indexacao
    join t in context.sistema_Indexes on u.idIndice equals t.id
    join l in context.sistema_Documentos on u.idDocumento equals l.id
    join v in context.sistema_DocType_Index on t.id equals v.indexId
    join m in context.sistema_DocType on v.docTypeId equals m.id
    where u.idDocumento == id
    select new Gedi.Models.OperacoesModel.getDocIndex
    { ...  }).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not solve my problem. Should I overwrite some class to get it done? Still remains the 7 itens in the List

Comment: Are you selecting the same columns from your sql statement?

Answer (score 5):

```
var docIndexModel = docIndexModelDup
    .GroupBy(x => x.Id)
    .Select(g => g.First());
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var distinctRowsById = docObj.Select(i => i.Id)
    .Distinct()
    .Select(i => docObj.First(o => o.Id == i)
```

Comment: I haven't tried it, but looking at your code makes me think that it won't remove duplicates since every row will of course have an Id that matches the distinct list of Id's from the same set..?

Comment: you are right, see it now please. i had this issue before and the only way i saw to solve it was this method

Comment: That will work. However, the performance is worse than all the other suggested answers, since it iterates over the `docObj` sequence *n* +1 times, where *n* is the number of distinct id:s. Just sayin'. Feliz Navidad, Nicolás.

Answer (score 0):

On your getDocIndex object, you need to implement the interface 
[IEquatable.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187.aspx) This will tell the Distinct method whether or not your objects are equal to each other when it does a comparison. This is the proper way to do comparisons with Distinct and it is much cleaner.

```
public class getDocIndex: IEquatable<getDocIndex> 
{
    ....
    public bool Equals(getDocIndex otherModel)
    {
        if (otherModel == null) 
            return false;
        return this.idName == otherModel.idName && this.idTipo == otherModel.idTipo
        && this.tamanho == otherModel.tamanho && this.caminho == otherModel.caminho;
    } 
}
```

After you implement this interface, you can continue calling distinct and it will work correctly.

Comment: But this won't affect the generated SQL, which seems to be the intention here.

Comment: I simply answered his question. "I want to remove repeated rows from a LIST using distinct." "But I still get the same 7 rows as if there is no DISTINCT at all.

Why?"

Answer (score 0):

Whenever using sql, use .Distinct() before .ToList().
This probably will solve the problem.
For example:

```
var ans = (from x in xyx
             where ...
             select new ...
             {
                a = ...,
                b = ...
             }).Distinct().ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Distinct works only Lambda ..like this

```
var data =_CustomerCompanyRepository.GetAll().Where(p => (p.PrimaryUser == userid || p.SecondayUser == userid)).Distinct();
```

if we want to remove duplicates in linq query ..use group

```
 var Account = (from c in depa join u in UserManager.Users on c.Id equals u.DepartmentId
                               group c by c into g
                               select new datadto{ Id = g.Key.Id, Name = g.Key.DepatmentName }).ToArray();
```